# Tkinter Tkk GUI not showing at boot

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, startup, raspberry-pi3

I'm new to Python as well as to Raspberry PI.

I have developped the below Python program using Tkinter library.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

# Test program
#libraries IMPORT
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO #/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/RPi
import time    
from time import sleep
try:
    from Tkinter import * #/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter
    from Tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk

# functions
def eseguiQUIT (event):
#routine spegnimento app
## chiusura interfaccia grafica
    root.destroy()
## Spegnimento canali GPIO
    GPIO.output(chan_list, GPIO.LOW)   # tutti i canali spenti 

## GPIOs
chan_list = [3,5,7,8,10,11,12,13,15,16,18,19,21,22,23,24,26,29,31]

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(chan_list,GPIO.OUT) # tutti i canali definiti come uscite
GPIO.output(chan_list, GPIO.LOW)   # tutti i canali spenti
sleep (2)
GPIO.output(chan_list[0], GPIO.HIGH)   # LED0 ON
sleep (1)
GPIO.output(chan_list[1], GPIO.HIGH)   # LED1 ON
sleep (1)
GPIO.output(chan_list[2], GPIO.HIGH)   # LED2 ON
sleep (1)
GPIO.output(chan_list[3], GPIO.HIGH)   # LED3 ON

### Graphic interface creation Tkinter e TTK
root = Tk()
root.title("COMANDO LUCI")
root.geometry('+20+20')
root.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)

#creazione frame principale
frame = ttk.Frame (root, borderwidth=5, )
## Configura righe e colonne del frame
for colonna in range (0,4):
    frame.columnconfigure(colonna, weight=1)
for righe in range (0,30):
    frame.rowconfigure(righe, weight=1)

frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

# Sotto frame Opzioni e generale
ContieniOG = LabelFrame(frame, borderwidth=1, relief="groove",text = "COMANDI e Opzioni")
ContieniOG.grid(column=0,columnspan =1, row=0, sticky="nw")

## Opzioni
QUIT = Button(ContieniOG, text ="QUIT", relief="groove",width="5", height = "1", fg = "black")
QUIT.grid(column=0,columnspan =1, row=0,sticky="nw")
QUIT.bind("<ButtonRelease>", eseguiQUIT)

#### Attivazione
mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

It runs well in the Python Shell as well as if I launch it with a terminal command but ....

I'm not able to see the GUI if I run it at boot (using several methods)
while the program apparently works, the LEDs on outputs are all lighting as expected and then I see the standard desktop.

Am I missing something ?

Thank you in advance for the help

Giga

Comment: show how you run it at boot. Do you run it after you login ? Only login user can have access to display/monitor.

Comment: BTW: you need only `root.mainloop()`. You can remove `mainloop()`

Comment: The raspberry logs me automatically no need of loggging

Comment: and thanks @furas for the optimization

Comment: I saw similar question on SO few days ago. System after login my run `.bashrc` or `.profile`. Every Linux environment (Gnone, KDE, other) may have folder `autostart` or submenu `autostart` in main menu. All depends which environment do you use.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up

Comment: I'm using Raspian and the last boot start method I used was to write in /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart

Comment: This solution (the only that partially works) starts the Tkinter GUI only if I open a terminal .